# Jolt transform JSON with escape character?

Tags: json, jolt

I am having a JSON string as below:

```json
{
  "multiref": "{\"test\":\"test2\"}"
}
```

I need to shift `test` to `local.test`. How can I do this if JSON is an escape character?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "right hand side" of the "multiref" is a String.   If you can un-String into actual JSON then Jolt could do the shift.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some extra functions with `modify-overwrite-beta` operations to change your string into an array and create your new object with the `shift` operation.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "multiref": "=split('\\{\"', @(1,multiref))",
      "multire*": "=lastElement"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "multiref": "=split('\"\\}', @(1,multiref))",
      "multire*": "=lastElement"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "multiref": "=split('\":\"', @(1,multiref))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "multiref": {
        "1": {
          "@": "local.@(2,[0])"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]